# How to open the folder of current open item and select that item?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a Sub that opens the Folder for the current open mail-item.

This makes sense if I have an item open, but have changed the mail-Folder inbetween, and want to open the right Folder straight away again.

```vb
Sub ordner_mail_oeffnen()
    On Error GoTo exit_sub
    'Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olitem As Outlook.mailitem
    'Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olitem = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Dim olfolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    FolderPath = GetPath(olitem)
    Set olfolder = GetFolder(FolderPath)
    olfolder.Display

    'those two lines are just for test purpose
    MsgBox "jetzt"
    Application.ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection

    Sleep (10000)
    Application.ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection
    'here comes the runtime-error (I try to translate) "-2147467259 (80004005) element can not be activated or deactivated, as id does not exist in the current view"
    Application.ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection olitem 
exit_sub:
exit_sub:
End Sub
```

Only after the error the new Folder is opened but does not select certain mail.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Explorer.ClearSelection` and `Explorer.AddToSelection` to select an item.

The current Explorer is returned from `Application.ActiveExplorer`.

Comment: thanks a lot, getting into the right direction. But: the "Display" seems to work quite late, even if I put a msgbox and a a sleep(10000) after this, the new Explorer is only displaed at the end of the code. Due to this I get an error when trying the .AddToSelection. I edit the question above...

Comment: Instead of displaying folder in a new window, you can reuse the current one by setting the Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder property to olfolder.

Comment: Instead of using MAPIFolder.Display, you can also use MAPIFolder.GetExplorer followed by Explorer.Display and use it instead of Application.ActiveExplorer

Answer (score 0):

You could continue to use `GetPath(olitem)` and `GetFolder(FolderPath)` but since the code was not included I cannot be sure.

Replace `olfolder.Display` with `Set ActiveExplorer = olfolder`.

Without `GetPath(olitem)` and `GetFolder(FolderPath)`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ordner_mail_oeffnen()

    Dim olitem As Object
    Dim olfolder As Folder

    Set olitem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set olfolder = olitem.Parent
    Set ActiveExplorer = olfolder

    ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection
    ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection olitem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that Outlook must be given time to bring up the new Display. This can be done using `DoEvents`. For me, the following works:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
Sub ordner_mail_oeffnen()
    
    Dim olitem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olitem = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Dim olfolder As MAPIFolder
    Set olfolder = olitem.Parent
    
    olfolder.Display
    
    'Sleep 10000             ' does not help
    'MsgBox ("Interruption") ' does not help
    DoEvents                 ' Important!

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(olitem) = False Then
        Stop ' We should not get here!
             ' But we will, if the line <DoEvents> is missing.
    End If
    
    Application.ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection
    Application.ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection olitem
End Sub
```

If you omit the `DoEvents`, the code will run into the `Stop` command. A previous `Sleep` or `MsgBox` will not help.
Caveat: when you debug the code step by step (F8), the initial problem will not show up.